# Need to change a user's email used for auth0 by admin

Tags: node.js, jwt, auth0

In the application, we are using auth0 to login to the application. we have two type of users, admin and agent. Need to update the agent's email associated with auth0 login by admin. How can we do that? there is a way a user can change his/her own email but here another person can change the email for someone. Need a help here

Go through: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/#!/Users/patch_users_by_id

but it is for user can change his/her own email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMza7El7IwE&feature=youtu.be

There is no out of the box solution, but the platform allows you to achieve the desired result via the management api. Let us know if you have questions. You can always visit the Auth0 Community if you want more eyes on the topic.